# Name of a proton bonded to a hydroxyl carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What do you call the proton in a C**H**-OH configuration?

When discussing an NMR spectrum, I can talk about the hydroxyl proton, but it seems clumsy to refer to "the proton on the hydroxyl carbon".

Answer (score 9):

I would call it the $\alpha$-proton to the $\ce{-OH}$. The alpha proton is the proton bonded to the alpha carbon (i.e., the hydroxyl carbon).